# How "large" should be a file to be tracked in git-lfs?

Tags: git

Git lfs was invented to help developers not to grow repository too much when they store large resource files, that perhaps get modified often.

[image: Courtesy of Github]

Picture above courtesy of [git-lfs.github.io](https://git-lfs.github.io).

I am asking for advice on enabling cases for using git-lfs. It's fun to know that if you have a resource, e.g. music, video and textures for a videogame, you can safely store them in a place different than the codebase.

But I would like to better understand what are possible enabling scenarios for git-lfs.

Examples:
 - Unit test data worth a few dozens megabytes that are used for testing integrations
 - Images (like icons) that are worth, say, a few megabytes, and do not get changed often. *I personally think they should be committed in regular storage in such a case*
 - Derived resources that you don't want to `.gitignore` in order not to rebuild them too often
 - Binary data that change really often

The above were just examples for which I have doubt on what storage to choose.

Is there a common best practice on when to use git-lfs and when not?